# For what dimensions of $\Omega$ is the embedding $H^1(\Omega) \subset L^6(\Omega)$ continuous?

Tags: continuity, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded open subset with a $C^1$- boundary.

Is the embedding
\begin{align}
     H^1(\Omega) \subset L^6(\Omega)
\end{align}
continuous for $n=1,2,3$?

I think it's clear for $n=3$, since we can apply the Sobolev embedding theorem to obtain that $\frac{1}{p^*}= \frac{1}{p}- \frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{6}$. Hence, the embedding is continuous for $n=3$.

But how can I argue for the cases $n=1$ and $n=2$?

Comment: For bounded sets, the embedding works for all $p \le p^*$.

Comment: Why does it work for all $p \leq p^*$? And $p^*$ is computed depending on $n$, so it's fixed for given $n$, isn't it? So for $n=1$, the above would mean that for $p\leq -2$, the embedding is continuous. How does that help?

Comment: For bounded sets, this follows by Hoelder inequality.

Comment: So, I have a concrete $p$ given, namely $p=2$. If I choose a concrete $n$, I can compute $p*$ and can conclude that $H^p(\Omega)$ is continuously embedded in $L^{p^*}(\Omega)$.  If I now change $n$, the dimension of $\Omega$, I  obtain a totally different $p^*$. Moreover, the first part of the Sobolev embedding theorem is only valid for the cases $p<n$, which means I cannot apply it to the cases $n=1,2$ and $p=2$. What can I do?

Comment: For $p=1$ you can choose $p^*=\infty$, for $p=2$ every $p^*<\infty$ works.

Comment: But I just want $p=2$ (as I am interested in $H^1(\Omega)$, but I want to keep the dimension of $\Omega$ denoted here by $n$ to be 1 or 2.